# Possible to return newest questions with a certain tag?

Tags: feature-request, api

I am not finding a way to return a list of new questions by tag with the new [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Am I missing something or is this not available? If this is not available, I most certainly request this feature.

Comment: Do you want something like "the most recent 10 questions with a certain tag?"

Comment: Yes, I want precisely that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get the 10 most recent questions of a tag, either on the [`/questions`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#pagesize=10&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=iphone&filter=!9Vbu7HaI(&site=stackoverflow&run=true) method or [`/search`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=iphone&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) method.

The parameters on both routes are the same, just set `tagged` to your tag (eg `iphone`), and `sort` to `creation`, and `order` to `desc`

So that's either:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions?order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=iphone&site=stackoverflow

or

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/search?order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=iphone&site=stackoverflow

The difference between the two is that if you search with multiple tags (separated by semi-colons), eg (`c#;iphone`):

- The `/questions` method will return questions which have both the `c#` **and** `iphone` tags.
- Whereas the `/search` method will return questions tagged either `c#` **or** `iphone` (or both).